# How to open same component outside of dashboard just in view mode which we are access after login

Tags: angular, authentication

I have a component named world survey which only I can access after login & once is user has authenticated but here is my another requirement, I want to open that (world survey) component outside of login as well (Please see in the picture ) just in view mode, if user try to do something activity like visiting other profile, etc. then it should show   a message, you are not logged in.
Please any person can help me with this that How  can I achieve that.
Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr9Nu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any guard for that router. Check the user login in the component, not in router guard. Inside your component when a user going to do any activity then you can check whether the user can perform that task or not and based on that you can either show a message or allow the user to perform the task.

Comment: But for that do I need to create a separate component  ?

Comment: because the same component I am using after login .

Comment: why did you add the login restriction for a whole component when that component accessible for all user?

Comment: Sorry! I did not get you

Comment: I just wanna open that component in view mode

Comment: but when user get logged in then he can do any activity

Comment: then add your condition inside your component, if they logged in they can do the activity otherwise only view mode.

Comment: but don't I need to create a separate component for that ?